# RxCocoa fails to archive via xcodebuild

Tags: swift, xcode, xcodebuild

I have a framework with RxSwift dependency added via SPM and when trying to archive my framework via the following script:

```
xcodebuild archive \
    -project Project.xcodeproj \
    -scheme Scheme \
    -destination "generic/platform=iOS" \
    -archivePath "archives/Release-iOS" \
    SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
    BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
```

It fails like so:

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    SwiftVerifyEmittedModuleInterface normal arm64 Verifying\ emitted\ module\ interface\ RxCocoa.private.swiftinterface /Users/.../DerivedData/Project-ericldteywlbdydxfxsgvkaxpvdj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Project/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/RxSwift.build/Release-iphoneos/RxCocoa.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RxCocoa.private.swiftinterface (in target 'RxCocoa' from project 'RxSwift')
    SwiftVerifyEmittedModuleInterface normal arm64 Verifying\ emitted\ module\ interface\ RxCocoa.swiftinterface /Users/.../DerivedData/Project-ericldteywlbdydxfxsgvkaxpvdj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Project/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/RxSwift.build/Release-iphoneos/RxCocoa.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RxCocoa.swiftinterface (in target 'RxCocoa' from project 'RxSwift')
(2 failures)
```

It does succeed if done though Xcode (Product -> Archive) but Xcode doesn't seem to be using xcodebuild in the back to archive it so it's hard to compare.

I'm using Xcode 14.3.1 and latest version of RxSwift 6.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
xcodebuild archive \
    -project Project.xcodeproj \
    -scheme Scheme \
    -destination "generic/platform=iOS" \
    -archivePath "archives/Release-iOS" \
    SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
    BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-no-verify-emitted-module-interface"
```